# php validate email address based on the domain name

Tags: php, regex, if-statement

I need to filter some email address based on the domain name :
Basically if the domain name is yahoo-inc.com, facebook.com, baboo.com .. (and a few others) the function should do something and if the domain is different it should do something else . 
 The only way I know to do this is to use a pattern/regex with preg_match_all and create cases/conditions for each balcklisted domain (e.g if domain = yahoo-inc) do this elseif (domain == facebook.com ) do this ... etc but I need to know if there is a more simple/concis way to include all the domains that I want to filter in a single variable/array and then apply only 2 conditions (e.g if email is in black list {do something } else {do something else}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the domain portion (i.e. everything after the last '@'), down case it, and then use `in_array` to check whether it's in your blacklist:

```
$blacklist = array('yahoo-inc.com', 'facebook.com', ...);
if (in_array($domain, $blacklist)) {
    // bad domain
} else {
    // good domain
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to @Alnitak here is the full code to do what you need

```
$domain = explode("@", $emailAddress);
$domain = $domain[(count($domain)-1)];
$blacklist = array('yahoo-inc.com', 'facebook.com', ...);
if (in_array($domain, $blacklist)) {
    // bad domain
} else {
    // good domain
}
```

Comment: technically you should take the last element of `$domain`, which is not guaranteed to be `[1]`.  `"A@B"@C` is a legal e-mail address.

Answer (score 1):

Well here's a very simple way to do this, a VALID email address should only ever contain a single `@` symbol, so aslong as it validation you can just explode the string by `@` and collect the second segment.

Example:

```
if (filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    //Valid Email:
    $parts = explode("@",$user_email);

    /*
         * You may want to use in_array if you already have a compiled array
         * The switch statement is mainly used to show visually the check.
    */
    switch(strtolower($parts[1]))
    {
         case 'facebook.com':
         case 'gmail.com':
         case 'googlemail.com':
             //Do Something
         break;
         default:
             //Do something else
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would require a case for each blacklisted domain, it's better to store all the blacklisted domains in one array and then compare using in_array.