# How to understand if an e-mail address is an education e-mail address or not?

Tags: php, email, web, laravel

I want only college students to be able to sign up my website, but I couldn't figure out how to control that. I also want .edu.fr, edu.tr or other .edu extensions to be able to join my website not just .edu's. I was thinking about using some reg-ex but I couldn't find any solution. I would be glad if someone can help me?

Shouldn't be that important but I am using PHP with laravel framework.

Comment: Check out these two posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136678/php-validate-email-address-based-on-the-domain-name and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609195/parse-rfc-822-compliant-addresses-in-a-to-header

Comment: It seems like a lost cause to me. You can't guarantee the email will follow any format. For instance, my university gives students a ulaval.ca email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most educational institutions have domain names that follow these pattern:

```
uni.edu
uni.edu.fr
uni.ac.uk
```

The following regular expression covers all such cases:

```
/(\.edu(\.[a-z]+)?|\.ac\.[a-z]+)$/
```

You can add cases to the regex as needed.  Check that the email is real by sending an automated email with a confirmation link.

Corresponding PHP:

```
if (preg_match('/(\.edu(\.[a-zA-Z]+)?|\.ac\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/i', $domain)) {
    // allow
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's not a great way to do it, but one possible way might be to explode the address using the @ symbol:

```
// Split the email address into 2 values of an array using the @ symbol as delimiter.
$emailParts = explode('@', $theEmailAddress);
// If the second part (domain part) contains .edu, period, country code or just .edu, then allow signup.
if (preg_match('/\.edu\.[^.]+$/i', trim($emailParts[1])) || preg_match('/\.edu$/i', trim($emailParts[1]))) {
    // Use the above if you are assuming that the country codes can be any number of characters. If you know for sure country codes are 2 chars, use this condition:
    // (preg_match('/\.edu\.[^.]{2}$/i', trim($emailParts[1])) || preg_match('/\.edu$/i', trim($emailParts[1])))
    // Allow signup
}
```

Of course, this does NOT guarantee that the domain or the email address is an existing one!